# Evaluating Fuzzy IF THEN Rule Consistency

Tags: correlation, fuzzy

I have about 125 rules for a fuzzy inference system and would like to plot/evaluate all the antecedents and consequents to ensure the rules are not in conflict.

For example, I have the following rule:

streamdistance["low"] & streammorder["low"] & slope["low"], vulnerability["low"]

| rule | strmdist | strmord | slope | vul |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | low | low | low | low |
| 1 | low | low | medium | low |
| 2 | low | low | medhigh | low |
| 3 | low | low | high | low |
| 4 | low | low | vryhigh | medium |
| 5 | low | medium | low | low |
| 6 | low | medium | medium | medium |
| 7 | low | medium | medhigh | high |
| 8 | low | medium | high | high |
| 9 | low | medium | vryhigh | high |
| 10 | low | medhigh | low | medium |

I would like to evaluate all 125 consequents and understand if the vulnerability level is consistent among the three antecedents.  I'm looking for a method to check the quality of the rule base.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "consistent". Do you mean that the rule is left-total and right-unique, making it a function?

Comment: Apparently I don't understand fuzzy logic. I'm looking at [fuzzy rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_rule) and it isn't obvious what is fuzzy about *modus ponens* and *modus tollens*. Are these constructed with something like the [Zadah operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic#Fuzzy_logic_operators)?

Comment: Although it won't answer your question, I'll share an impression. You could convert your ordinal variables into their eCDF scores and plot these scores for strmdist, strmord, and slope on a ternary plot with each point color-coded by vul.

Comment: @Galen I have done some reading and believe what I am looking for is rule conflict.  Where two rules with different inputs results in the same output.  This is hard because many of the rules will result in conflict.  I need to think some more about my question and the result I am looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It sounds like your initial thinking was the right-unique property of a function.